# Calculating binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am familiar with:

$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$

Now, i have an excercise in calculus which gets to the point that we should calculate:

$$
\frac{\binom{3n+1}{n+1}}{\binom{3n}{n}}
$$

The answer says that:

$$
\frac{\binom{3n+1}{n+1}}{\binom{3n}{n}} = \frac{(3n+3)!n!(2n)!}{(3n)!(2n+2)!(n+1)!}
$$

I dont understand how they got to thise from the formula i showed, how, for example, they got to $(3n+3)$, $(2n+2)$?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the result, I think the original questions was meant to show,

$$ \frac{ \left( 3(n+1) \atop n+1 \right) } { \left( 3n \atop n \right) } = \frac{(3n+3)!}{(n+1)!(2n+2)!} \cdot \frac{ n!(2n)! }{(3n)!}. $$

which is simply applying the formula.

The expression you have simplifies to $$\frac{3n+1}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Yes, looking at the start of the question again i think you are right. There was propably a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.